# Offset Column for table in Word

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm wanting to create a table in word which has the last column offset like so:
[image: appreciate my drawing skills]

Would anybody be able to help me?

Comment: You need to insert either all 4 Columns and adjust Column 3 and 4 using Horizontal line, or Insert 2 Columns as 2X10 then 1x4 and 1x3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use powershell to automate table creation.

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application

$word.visible = $true
$word.application.DisplayAlerts = 0
$document = $word.documents.add()
$selection = $word.selection
$selection.Font.Name = "Arial"
$selection.Font.Size = 14
$selection.Font.Bold = $true;

$number_Of_Rows = 10
$number_Of_Columns = 4
$paragraph = $document.Content.Paragraphs.Add()
$Range = $paragraph.Range
$Table = $document.Tables.Add($Range,$number_Of_Rows,$number_Of_Columns)
$Table.Borders.Enable = 1
$BorderTop = "-1"
$BorderLeft = "-2"
$BorderBottom = "-3"
$BorderRight = "-4"
$Table = $document.Tables.item(1)
$Table.Rows.Height = 40

$Table.Cell(1, 1).Merge($Table.Cell(2, 1))
$Table.Cell(1,1).Range.Text = "a"
$Table.Cell(3, 1).Merge($Table.Cell(4, 1))
$Table.Cell(5, 1).Merge($Table.Cell(6, 1))
$Table.Cell(7, 1).Merge($Table.Cell(8, 1))
$Table.Cell(9, 1).Merge($Table.Cell(10, 1))

$Table.Cell(1, 2).Merge($Table.Cell(2, 2))
$Table.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "b"
$Table.Cell(3, 2).Merge($Table.Cell(4, 2))
$Table.Cell(5, 2).Merge($Table.Cell(6, 2))
$Table.Cell(7, 2).Merge($Table.Cell(8, 2))
$Table.Cell(9, 2).Merge($Table.Cell(10, 2))

$Table.Cell(2, 3).Merge($Table.Cell(3, 3))
$Table.Cell(2, 3).Range.Text = "c"
$Table.Cell(4, 3).Merge($Table.Cell(5, 3))
$Table.Cell(6, 3).Merge($Table.Cell(7, 3))
$Table.Cell(8, 3).Merge($Table.Cell(9, 3))

$Table.Cell(3, 4).Merge($Table.Cell(4, 4))
$Table.Cell(3, 4).Range.Text = "d"
$Table.Cell(5, 4).Merge($Table.Cell(6, 4))
$Table.Cell(7, 4).Merge($Table.Cell(8, 4))

$Table.cell(1, 3).Range.Borders.item($BorderTop).LineStyle = 0
$Table.cell(1, 3).Range.Borders.item($BorderRight).LineStyle = 0
$Table.cell(1, 4).Range.Borders.item($BorderTop).LineStyle = 0
$Table.cell(1, 4).Range.Borders.item($BorderRight).LineStyle = 0
$Table.cell(2, 4).Range.Borders.item($BorderTop).LineStyle = 0
$Table.cell(2, 4).Range.Borders.item($BorderRight).LineStyle = 0

$Table.cell(9, 4).Range.Borders.item($BorderRight).LineStyle = 0
$Table.cell(9, 4).Range.Borders.item($BorderBottom).LineStyle = 0
$Table.cell(10, 4).Range.Borders.item($BorderRight).LineStyle = 0
$Table.cell(10, 4).Range.Borders.item($BorderBottom).LineStyle = 0
$Table.cell(10, 3).Range.Borders.item($BorderRight).LineStyle = 0
$Table.cell(10, 3).Range.Borders.item($BorderBottom).LineStyle = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create tables *a* and *b* by using the *create table* function, then tables *c* and *d* draw them with the pencil.

Answer (score 0):

Offsetting the cells of the table can be done by using the "split cell button" and then highlighting the cells you want to create by using the "merge cell button". It's a little weird, but once you get going it's easy to understand.